My thinkpad E15 being too slow, sluggish and laggy. Load average above 115. I have reinstalled ubuntu twice but it is still not performing well,
Result of Neofetch
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
Host: 20TD003KUS ThinkPad E15 Gen 2
Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic
Uptime: 1 hour, 52 mins
Packages: 2277 (dpkg), 16 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.1.16
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 42.9
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7 (8) @ 4.200GHz
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
Memory: 1902MiB / 15683MiB
Result of htop
Tasks: 138, 483 thr; 2 running
Load average: 117, 120, 124
Uptime: 01:20:53
Mem: 2.04G/15.3G
Swp: 0K/2.00G

Impossible to tell what is going on. What is the process that consumes the most CPU, and how much is that, on a scale from 0-100%?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Jos The main issue is laggy performance. The main issue is with Google Chrome. The % spikes quickly and drops down continuosly most of the time when the lag occurs. It ranges from 0-40%. and noticed even the gnome-terminal uses around 20-34% sometimes. I'm new to linux so I'm confused if the issue is with me or the machine or the O.S.

Is there anyway I can talk to someone one-on-one or sth like that so I can actually show the problem or maybe explain it with visuals?? @Jos

We have a general chat room where people might like to look at your system. However, you need a certain amount of reputation. I'll upvote your question for that reason, and if enough others do likewise, you will be allowed in.
